# Chip in bottom of moka pot

Tags: moka

My moka pot has a chip in the bottom and I can't tell if it has mold in it, or if it is just broken off aluminum. It's aluminum bialetti 6 cup and I've had it for about a year or so. I tried descaling and just scrubbing the bottom to make sure, but I can't tell. I then moved and haven't used it in a while but I wanted to make sure it was safe to use. I can touch it with my finger and pieces of what feel like the metal sometimes rub off.[image]

Comment: From what I can see, this issue is on the outside, therefore it is safe to use. The only problem that I can think of is the thickness of what is left of it, It could give up from the pressure while boiling.